# Looking to Submit Rails Form Only After Successful Stripe Checkout Payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am using Rails 4.2, and trying to integrate Stripe Checkout (https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails) in my rails app and have a scenario I haven't seen outlined anywhere. Note: I tried custom form integration from a number of online resources but couldn't get it to work so opted to give checkout a go.

In my rails app, I have an orders table, and the main thing I'm trying to accomplish is having a form where the user can submit their personal information (non-payment) to place an order. Then, the stripe checkout integration will allow them to pay; however, a record of the order will not be created in the database without a stripe charge being logged. I've been unable to accomplish this with using the separate "charges" controller that stripe suggests, and also tried incorporating the stripe code into my orders controller (see below).

I should note that I **HAVE** been able to get checkout button to submit to stripe and the charges are processed, but **HAVE NOT** been able to get a order record to be created in my database.

I have searched far and wide for an answer to this question (currently waiting on response from stripe support). Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

**orders_controller.rb**

*(this is the example where I tried combining the stripe code from the charges controller they suggest into my own orders controller. i'm not sure now what to do after the charge is processed to get it to submit the form)*

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(order_params)

  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => 'example@stripe.com',
    :card  => params[:stripeToken]
  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => 5000,
    :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
    :currency    => 'usd'
  )

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    render 'new'
  end
```

**orders/new.html.erb**

*(I am leaving out code for all the other fields in my form, this just shows my form submit button and the stripe checkout button. Ideally I could combine the actions into one button, or only have the submit go through when the payment successfully processes through stripe)*

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
    // lots of form fields
<%= f.submit %>

<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
      data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
      data-description="A month's subscription"
      data-amount="500"></script>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Typically you would do...

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(order_params)
  charge_error = nil

  if @order.valid?
    begin
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => 'example@stripe.com',
        :card  => params[:stripeToken])

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount      => 5000,
        :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
        :currency    => 'usd')

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      charge_error = e.message
    end
    if charge_error
      flash[:error] = charge_error
      render :new
    else
      @order.save
      redirect_to (successful page)
    end
  else
    flash[:error] = 'one or more errors in your order'
    render :new
  end
end
```

This way the charge isn't made unless the @order is validated, and the @order isn't saved unless the charge is successful.

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked like a charm!