# Rails Stripe payment and form using 1 submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, stripe-payments, ruby-on-rails-4.2

My question is very similar to [Looking to Submit Rails Form Only After Successful Stripe Checkout Payment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27933855/looking-to-submit-rails-form-only-after-successful-stripe-checkout-payment). I tried the solution accepted there but it did not work for me.

I am using Rails 4.2, Stripe integration is already implemented and I added a `Survey` form to the same page as the Stripe payment page. The Survey form displays correctly and saves if I use the submit button from the partial. But I am trying to submit the form (create and save) if the form and the credit card payment is valid using **one** submit button on the Stripe payment page.

It looks like the Stripe payment form is being submitted through js.

payments/partials/_ticket_payment_panel.html

```
<form action='/payments/pay_for/receive_payments' id="ticket-form" method="POST">
  // form fields 
</form>


<% content_for :scripts do %>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function () {
        var $form = $('#ticket-form');
        //var $survey = $('#survey-form');
        $form.submit(function (event) {
            // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks:
            $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', true);
            // Request a token from Stripe:
            Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
            // Prevent the form from being submitted:
            return false;
        });
    });

    function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
        var $form = $('#ticket-form');
        if (response.error) {
            // Show the errors on the form
            $('.submit').removeProp('disabled');
        } else {
            // response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
            var token = response.id;
            // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
            //execute this block only if plan exists -> helpers/payments/application_helper.rb

            $form.get(0).submit();
        }
    }
  </script>

<% end %>
```

The Stripe submit works but it does not submit the Survey form. I tried adding `var $survey = $('#survey-form');` and submit in the js. But it either only submits the form and not the Stripe payment or vice versa depending on which comes first.

I also tried to add the save in the controller.

pay_for_controller

```
def receive_payments
  @survey = Survey.new
  @survey.userprofile_id = current_user.userprofile.id
  skills = params[:skills]
  work_type = params[:work_type]
  @survey.save

  //credit card attempts, delayed jobs code 
end
```

This is my survey form

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@survey, :html => { :id => "survey-form" } ) do |f| %>

  //form fields 
  <%= f.submit "Apply", class: 'action-btn btn-rounded btn-large' %>

<% end %>
```

Currently, individually they submit/save correctly so I think the link between the model and controller are fine. But I can't seem to alter the js code or controller to get both the Survey form and the Stripe payment to save.

Comment: Are these forms completely separate from each other or do you have one form inside of another?

Comment: The forms are completely separate from each other. But both forms are rendered in the same page partial.

Comment: You can't submit two different form from single request. You can solve this situation in two ways. 1. Combine both form into single form, 2. save the `survey` form data via AJAX call and submit stripe form upon response from your AJAX call.

Comment: 1. If I combine both forms into a single form, then I would not be able to save certain fields to `survey` table and credit card info to `Ticket` table?
2. I will try this suggestion out, does this mean there are 2 buttons? One to submit `survey` form data via AJAX. Then show stripe form upon successful `survey` form submit and submit stripe form?

Comment: @tshckr provided a solution logic for single form submit

Answer (score 0):

> Following rough logic explained solution by single submission

**Assuming Stripe request will be called when two forms (stripe, survey) are ready. Then you need to make a AJAX request (post survey data) after successfully getting `token` from Stripe, then Stripe form submit**

```
function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
        var $form = $('#ticket-form');
        if (response.error) {
            $('.submit').removeProp('disabled');
        } else {
            var token = response.id;
            //here is the ajax call to submit survey
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "url/of/your/survey/form/post",
              data: "{empid: " + empid + "}",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(result){
                   //submit stripe form only if the survey data saved
                   $form.get(0).submit();
              },
              error: function(){
                   //handle error situation if post request failed
              }
            });
        }
    }
```